# CDI, how to substitute an injected bean with another

Tags: cdi

I started recently using CDI in one of projects i work and i have a specific situation where i could not find a solution yet. Could someone give me some hints? I would really appreciate.

I have an application that uses a custom framework.

1. In the custom framework i have one ejb that injects a bean.

   ```
   public class MyEjb implements MyEjbBI {
       ...
       private IServiceHolder serviceHolder;
       ...
   }

   public interface IServiceHolder {
       ...
   }

   public class DefaultServiceHolder implements IServiceHolder {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. In my application, the above mentioned code is packed into one jar file and that jar contains also one bean.xml file that i cannot change, so i cannot use @Alternative on my own implementation

   ```
   public class MyServiceHolder extends IServiceHolder
   {
       ...
   }
   ```

**My question:** is any possibility to substitute at runtime the injected serviceHolder from "MyEjb"(default one) with "MyServiceHolder" implementation?

I mention that i can do changes also in framework code. 
I have read something about producer methods but i do not really understand how to use them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with @Alternative, but you need @Priority to declare your implementation a selected alternatives for the application:

```java
@Alternative @Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION)
public class MyServiceHolder implements IServiceHolder {
   ...
}
```

The CDI Spec says:

**5.1 Modularity**
An alternative is not available for injection, lookup or EL resolution to classes or JSP/JSF pages in a module unless the module is a bean archive and the alternative is explicitly selected for the bean archive **or the application**.

**5.1.4 Inter-module injection**
A bean is available for injection in a certain module if:

- the bean is not an interceptor or decorator
- the bean is enabled,
- the bean is either not an alternative, or the module is a bean archive and the bean is a selected alternative of the bean archive, or the bean is a **selected alternative of the application**, and
- the bean class is required to be accessible to classes in the module, according to the class accessibility requirements of the module architecture.

You don't even need to declare your CDI as alternative in **your own beans.xml** though:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd" 
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
    <!--Using @Priority you dont need to specify alternative here-->
</beans>
```